# Lodash FP Curry and TypeScript: How Do I Maintain Type Declarations After Currying a Function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, lodash, currying

The Function

```js
const getPropsFromObject = <P extends keyof T, T extends object>
    (props: P | P[], target: T): T[P][] => flow(
        castArray,
        map(partialRight(get, [target]))
    )(target)
```

This function works great:

```js
const data = {a: 5, b: 6}
const values = getPropsFromObject(["a", "b"], data);
// number[]
```

The intellisense comes back really clear and concise and I know what I'm going to be getting as a result.

However, when I wrap this same function in `curry`:

```js
export const getAll = curry(getPropsFromObject);

// const getAll: (...args:any[]) => any

const data = {a: 5, b: 6}
const values = getAll(["a", "b"], data);

// const values: any
```

From what I've been reading in the TypeScript Handbook, overloads are usually used in this situation. However, I am not able to find example of using overloads with a pointfree style of functional programming/composable functions.

Comment: I am not an expert of `lodash/fp`, I assume `_.props` is curried out of the box already... Have you tried that?

Comment: @Hitmands I'm not so much focused on the implementation as much as I am wondering how not not lose type definitions when currying a function. I may just be out of luck, but I wanted to see if there was a way to do functional programming like this in TypeScript.

Comment: tried https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts already?